# Is there a better way to structure the embedded SELECT Statement within this SELECT Statement?

Tags: mysql, database

In the following `MySQL` code segment I am using two embedded `SELECT` statements within a single `SELECT` statement to return some information from my database. It is currently working correctly, but I am unsure if the two embedded `SELECT` statements are being correctly utilized.

```
SELECT
  E.ID AS DEBATE_GROUPS_ID,
  A.TITLE AS STARTER_PACK_TITLE,
  B.TITLE AS UNITS_TITLE,
  B.UNIT_CODE AS UNITS_CODE,
  (SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM USERS WHERE ID = A.ACADEMIC_ID) AS ACADEMIC_FIRSTNAME, 
  (SELECT LAST_NAME FROM USERS WHERE ID = A.ACADEMIC_ID) AS ACADEMIC_LASTNAME,
  D.DATE_DUE AS DEBATES_DUE_DATE
FROM
  STARTER_PACKS A,
  UNITS B,
  USERS C,
  DEBATES D,
  DEBATE_GROUPS E
WHERE
  D.ID = E.DEBATE_ID AND E.STUDENT_ID = C.ID AND C.ID = 12
```

Therefore, my question is...

> Is what I'm doing with the embedded `SELECT` statements correct or is there a better alternative in terms of improving efficiency or readability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with a `JOIN` , although your query seems totaly wrong, you almost don't have any join conditions!

```
SELECT
  E.ID AS DEBATE_GROUPS_ID,
  A.TITLE AS STARTER_PACK_TITLE,
  B.TITLE AS UNITS_TITLE,
  B.UNIT_CODE AS UNITS_CODE,
  C.FIRSTNAME AS ACADEMIC_FIRSTNAME, 
  C.LASTNAME AS ACADEMIC_LASTNAME,
  D.DATE_DUE AS DEBATES_DUE_DATE
FROM
  STARTER_PACKS A
  INNER JOIN UNITS B ON(a.Column = B.Column)
  INNER JOIN USERS C ON(C.ID = A.ACADEMIC_ID)
  INNER JOIN DEBATES D ON (SomeColumn = D.Column)
  INNER JOIN DEBATE_GROUPS E ON(D.ID = E.DEBATE_ID AND E.STUDENT_ID = C.ID)
WHERE
  C.ID = 12
```

Please use the correct syntax of a explicit joins, this will help you avoid this type of problems . Replace those lines with the actual columns relations :

```
  INNER JOIN UNITS B ON(a.Column = B.Column)
  INNER JOIN DEBATES D ON (SomeColumn = D.Column)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not completely clear what is the aim of this query, but for what I can see, you can replace

```
(SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM USERS WHERE ID = A.ACADEMIC_ID) AS ACADEMIC_FIRSTNAME

with C.FIRST_NAME AS ACADEMIC_FIRSTNAME 

and

(SELECT LAST_NAME FROM USERS WHERE ID = A.ACADEMIC_ID) AS ACADEMIC_LASTNAME 

with C.LAST_NAME AS ACADEMIC_LASTNAME

add also a where clause to join USERS and STARTER_PACKS tables `AND C.ID = A.ACADEMIC_ID
```

Hope it helps.
Simone